# I am executing os.system ("unit run"+ directoryPath+" urun shell"), which opens the shell prompt of the unit, how to run commands on the shell promt?

Tags: python, automation, teamcenter

I am running a command `os.system("unit run" + directoryPath + " urun shell")`, which opens the shell prompt of the unit. How should I run commands on the shell prompt that is a whole new prompt getting open up with Python?

I tried executing the command `os.system("unit run" + directoryPath + " urun shell /c command")`, but that didn't worked as I was expecting that the command should have ran on the shell prompt.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can just call `os.system()` again with your shell-command.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) module:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["unit", "run", directoryPath, "urun" "shell"], shell=True, check=True)
```

Note you may need to include escaped quote marks in the `directoryPath` value:

```
directoryPath = '"some directory path"'
```